# navigation problem?

Tags: iphone

I have a view A where I have a code to push it to view B using:
[navController pushViewController:SecondViewController animated:YES];

when I get there and press back, the button says firstViewcontroller.
But when I press the buttons again to push it to the secondview again.
instead of showing 'firstviewcontroller' the buttons says secondviewcontroller.
and for some reason, my navigation-stack is adding and adding the secondview.

Can someone tell me what I do wrong?
I can't find any problem in my code.

Edit:
I have changed my code to:

```
FirstViewController *aFirstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [navController pushViewController:aFirstViewController animated:YES];
        [aFirstViewController release];
```

and it is still not working:S

Comment: the code seems to be correct ...

Comment: yeah I found out another thing was causing the problem

Answer (score -1):

I think u had not released the object of your SecondView.....
Anyways Put this at the place where u r giving your navigation code

```
SecondViewController *viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [SecondViewController release];
```